# SSIS OLE DB Destination to DB2 (iSeries)

Tags: ssis, db2, oledb

I have an SSIS package the moves data from SQL Server to DB2 (iSeries). My OLE DB Destination has a data access mode of SQL command with the following SQL:

```
SELECT
IUWHDP      -- TBDepartment
,IUBATID        -- TBBatchId
,IUADDTS    -- TBTimestamp
,IUADDUC    -- TBUCTimestamp
,IUSTATUS   -- TBStatus
,IUSTSTS        -- TBStatusTimestamp
,IUSTSUC        -- TBStatusUCTimestamp
,IUTEXT     -- TBStatusText
,IUWHSE     -- TBWarehouse
,IUUTYP     -- TBUpdateType
,IUITEM     -- TBItemNumber
,IUTYPE     -- TBItemType
,IUDESC     -- TBItemDescription
,IUSTYP     -- TBSection
,IUDESG     -- TBDesignation
,IUACTV     -- TBActivityZone
,IUBLD      -- TBBuildCode
,IUPDSC     -- TBPackDescription
,IUUM1      -- TBNormalUOM
,IUFLG1     -- TBAllowBreakdown
,IUUMQ2     -- TBBreakdownQty   
,IUFLG2     -- TBAllowBreakdown2
,IUULEN     -- TBLength
,IUUHGT     -- TBHeight
,IUUWDT     -- TBWidth
,IUSWGT     -- TBWeight
,IUCWGT     -- TBCatchWeightItem
,IUUMQ3     -- TBBreakdownQty2
,IUREPL     -- TBReplenishmentLevel
,IUBLNK     -- TBGrossWeight
,IUFLGD     -- TBDateSensitive
,IUFLGB     -- TBAllowBulkPicks
,IUSLIF     -- TBShelfLifeDays
,IUNDAY     -- TBNoticeDays
,IUTIE      -- TBTie
,IUHIGH     -- TBHigh
,IUMFLG     -- TBManufacturerDateItem
,IUDDAY     -- TBDistributorDays
,IUUDAY     -- TBEndUserDays
,IUMDAY     -- TBManShelfLifeDays
,IUMITM     -- TBMasterItemNumber
,IUNSLT     -- TBNonSlottedItem
,IUXDCK     -- TBCrossdockItem
,IUBNBR     -- TBBuyerNumber
,IULOT      -- TBLotCodeItem
,IULTRK     -- TBLicenseTrackingItem
,IUODAY     -- TBNumberOfDaysOut
,IUPQN1     -- TBRepackParentNormal
,IUPQN2     -- TBRepackParentBreakdown1
,IUPQN3     -- TBRepackParentBreakdown2
,IUCUBE     -- TBCube
```

FROM
    "PIRF002"."IMPSITMN"

I'm getting the following errors:

> [OLE DB Destination [174]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "IBMDA400 Command"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "SQL0104: Token . was not valid. Valid tokens: .
>   Cause . . . . . :   A syntax error was detected at token ..  Token . is not a valid token.  A partial list of valid tokens is .  This list assumes that the statement is correct up to the token.  The error may be earlier in the statement, but the syntax of the statement appears to be valid up to this point. Recovery  . . . :   Do one or more of the following and try the request again: -- Verify the SQL statement in the area of the token .. Correct the statement.  The error could be a missing comma or quotation mark, it could be a misspelled word, or it could be related to the order of clauses. -- If the error token is , correct the SQL statement because it does not end with a valid clause.".
>
> [OLE DB Destination [174]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (174) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (187). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

If I run the same SQL against the DB2 database using IBM Data Studio it runs without issues so I believe the SQL is correct. And from the OLE DB Destination I can successfully Preview the data in the table. But when I run the package from VS 2015 I get the errors. I have done some searching but haven't found a solution yet. And ideas what might cause this?